# Contact Form 7 как сделать чтоб reply письма автоматом вписать емейл пользователя который написал в форму свой емейл

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-plugin

Подскажите, как можно изменить строку "From", чтобы при нажатии reply данного сообщения емейл пользователя автоматически подставлялся в строку «Кому»?

[image: scr-1]

[image: scr-2]

Вариант [your-name] [your-email] - не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На вкладке mail есть Additional headers.

Туда: Reply-To: [your-email]